# Seg fault when changing values on a 2D Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create random coordinates but to make sure they aren't used I decided to create a 2D array initialized at 0 to show each space is empty.

I'm using this function for the randomness:

```
int randomNoGenerator(int limit)
{
   std::random_device r;

   std::default_random_engine e1(r());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, limit);
   int rand = uniform_dist(e1);
   return rand;
}
```

And my main:

```
int main(void)
{
    int numRows = 5;
    int numCols = 7;
    int **occupiedSpace;

    occupiedSpace = (int **)calloc(numRows, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        occupiedSpace[i] = (int *)calloc(numCols, sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int match = 1;
        x = randomNoGenerator(numCols);
        y = randomNoGenerator(numRows);

        //This is where the crash is happening?
        occupiedSpace[x][y] = 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

My ultimate goal was to have something like where if it's empty it just replaces it with a 1. Otherwise it keeps generating X, Y if it's already occupied.

```
while (match)
        {
            x = randomNoGenerator(numCols);
            y = randomNoGenerator(numRows);
            if(occupiedSpace[x][y] = 0)
                {
                occupiedSpace[x][y] = 1;
                match = 0;
                }
        }
```

Comment: You should move the declarations of `std::random_device` and `std::default_random_engine` outside of the function, in `main`, because initializing those more than once in a program is a waste. Also, what do you need those coordinates for? Are you going to use that "2D array" in any other way or is it just for bookkeeping (limited to the random generation) purposes?

Comment: I will be placing various object types randomly on a grid and need to be sure I'm not placing anything on top of anything else. I figured when they're generated they would check occupiedSpace to see if their space is valid or not before using that space. After they're finished occupiedSpace won't be used again (as far as I know right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generating your `x` and `y` coordinate the wrong way round. The outer index is the row, the inner index is the column, so you should do:

```
x = randomNoGenerator(numRows); // instead of numCols
y = randomNoGenerator(numCols); // instead of numRows
```

Then, you set up your random generator with wrong numbers. It should be `uniform_dist(0, limit - 1)` instead of `uniform_dist(1, limit)` since row and column indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Thank you, I figured I was using calloc incorrectly so that was all my focus was on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use std:array instead calloc :

```
   std::array<std::array<int,5>,7> occupiedSpace;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
        { for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) occupiedSpace[i][j] = 0 ; 
        }
```

Comment: You switched row and column length. And: If we're talking nicer ways to implement this, I'd say `int occupiedSpace[5][7]{};` is hard to beat.